# Cloud9 IDE + Rails App: CSS Background Image Not Showing on .erb page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide

This question has been asked many times but i can't resolve it.

I am trying to show an image on a ruby on rails app page on Cloud 9 IDE, but the image won't appear.

**CSS**

```
.hero-image {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("images/banner.jpg");

    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 50%;

    /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

**.erb page**

```
<div class="hero-image">
</div>
```

image is stored in app/assets/images

stylesheets directory: app/assets/stylesheets

I understand that the file path must be relative to the stylesheets page, which i have done correctly isn't it? I have also tried moving the image to the stylesheets directory and changing to `url("banner.jpg")`, but it still does not work.

**EDIT:**

Changing the url to a link of an image uploaded to google storage bucket does not work too.

```
background-image: url("https://storage.googleapis.com/#####");
```

Comment: have you tried `background-image: url(asset_path("images/banner.jpg"));`

Answer (score 0):

below changes should fix the issue :

- BG url in css to `background-image: url("/assets/benchmark.PNG");`
- the above  css mapped in erb file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/test.css">`
- to see the image ,the div should have some data as this is a div background:

`<div class="hero-image">
sdfdsfbfd <br/>sdfdsfbfd <br/>sdfdsfbfd <br/>sdfdsfbfd <br/>
</div>`